# MATLAB fft: for a large signal

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a signal vector of 300000 entries. In each iteration of a loop, I need to extract 2000 consecutive values from the signal vector, store it in in X vector, compute it's FFT and find the maximum frequency component in those 2000 values of X. In the next iteration, values from 2001 to 4000 from signal vector are to be extracted and a similar operation is to be performed. In each iteration, I need to know the maximum frequency. 
Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Sounds like a for loop incrementing by 2k each time and calculating a fft on the subset of the vector starting at that iteration location with a length of 2k. your FFT function should return the processed vector. push the max value from the FFT-returned vector into a result vector at the end of each iteration. finally after the loop breaks, return the result vector.

Comment: @Stephan Indeed this is straightforward if you know matlab. user3535492: *do you*? No one will write your code if you yourself can't. You even described the algorithm. Try programming it, and if you get errors, we might be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T=300; %acquisition time

fs=1000; %sampling rate;

t= 0:1/fs:(T-1/fs);    % 300 second @ 1kHz sample rate
fo=1;
f1=500;   
y=chirp(t,fo,T,f1); % 300000 samples, instead of your samples

nfft=2000; % sample number for fft
a=spectrogram(y,nfft,0,nfft,fs); % put your samples in y position

df=fs/nfft; % frequency resolution.. Change this as your resolution

[val ind]=max(a);

freq=df*(ind-1)
```

You could get max frequency of each fft with spectrogram, easily.